# Force formula to be evaluated at the usual time

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

[image]

I want to show  `My_Qty`, which is `{Table.1st_Qty}-{Table.2nd_qty}`, for each item. Currently it's showing "sum of `My_Qty`"

I understand that by using [WhilePrintingRecords](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic738.html) you retain total control as to when your formulas are evaluated. It forces the formula to be evaluated at its normal time, while printing records. But my current code is not doing anything.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
{Table.1st_Qty}-{Table.2nd_qty}
```

How can I alter this to evaluate at the right time?

Comment: Could you accomplish it with a running total field?

Comment: @heringer thank you for the reply! I did try in running total field but still the same: getting me the sum of the My_Qty values..

Comment: In wich section did you put My_Qty? Is "Table" the only table in your dataset? May you post a screenshot of your design?

Comment: @heringer Hi, I have uploaded the screenshot. I do have multiple tables but only two tables have the quantity fields I need to use. What I'm trying to achieve is Order qty - Ship qty = Back Order Qty.

Comment: @heringer feel free to ask me any question

Comment: @JamesT at which section have you put the formula?